# CSS :nth-child(even) doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have simple css and html code and i wondering why last vertical image not working. I mean it border and margin should be added to last element not first.

Is anyone knows why this not work?

See in https://jsfiddle.net/st2Lwrgj/

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.wrap {width: 250px; border: 1px solid red;overflow:hidden;}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
img.vertical {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
img.vertical:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: It's because the horizontal image breaks `:nth-child(even)`

Comment: In your code its applied to all the evens `:nth-child(even)` , so it will be second, fourth and sixth as your sixth is second last image and not the last image

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. (Your MCVE needs to include the HTML this CSS is operating on).

Answer (score 3):

`:nth-child(even)` will apply to every second image (second, fourth and so on). When you insert a horizontal image without the `.vertical` class you will break this order.

The following is a bit of a workaround, but the logic is pretty simple.

1. First we select every second image using `img.vertical:nth-child(even)`
2. We then find images without the `.vertical` class using`:not(.vertical)`
3. We then use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to select the following images and revert the order using `img.vertical:nth-child(odd)` instead of `even`.
4. As we have now applied borders to both odd and even ocurances of `img.vertical`, we need to remove the styling from the images we selected at point 1. We do this with a selector as set in point 3, but with `even` instead of `odd`: `img:not(.vertical) ~ img.vertical:nth-child(even)`

TLDR; change this part:

```
img.vertical:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Into the following:

```
img.vertical:nth-child(even),
img:not(.vertical) ~ img.vertical:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
img:not(.vertical) ~ img.vertical:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 0;
}
```

You can see how this works in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st2Lwrgj/2/).